# How to proxy JavaScript creation primitive

Tags: javascript, proxy, apply, primitive, construct

I want to do something when creating a string, for example:

```
String = new Proxy(String, {
    construct: (t, a) => {
        return { a: 123 }
    }
})
console.log(new String('q')) // { a: 123 }
```

However, if you use primitives, it doesn't work.

```
String = new Proxy(String, {
    construct: (t, a) => {
        return { a: 123 }
    }
})
console.log('1') // Expected: { a: 123 }, Actual: 1
```

Is there any way?

then the second question is,
when the runtime converts primitives, can I proxy the process?

```
var a = '123' // This is a primitive
console.log('123'.substring(0,1)) // Actual: 1
// The runtime wraps the primitive as a String object.
// then uses a substring, and then returns the primitive.
```

now:

```
String = new Proxy(String, {
    construct: (t, a) => {
        return { a: 123 }
    },
    apply: (target, object, args) => {
        return { a: 123 }
    }
})
console.log('1'.a) // Expected: 123 , Actual: undefined
```

I know I can add 'a' to the prototype of String to achieve the expectations.

But I want to be able to proxy access to **arbitrary** attributes for primitives.
(Is `'1'.*`, Is not jsut `'1'.a`)

Is there any way?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Proxies only work on objects, not on primitives. And no, you cannot intercept the internal (and optimised-away) process that converts a primitive to an object to access properties (including methods) on it.

Some of the operations involving primitives do use the methods on `String.prototype` / `Number.prototype` / `Boolean.prototype`, and you can overwrite these methods if you dare, but you cannot *replace* the entire prototype object for a proxy.