# JavaScript - proxy object to behave like primitive

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, metaprogramming

I'm trying to build a system that "caches" calls to a library before that library has loaded.

This is similar to what the Google Analytics "setup" code is doing with the `_gaq` variable - it's initialized as an array that "caches" calls to the real analytics endpoints until the `ga.js` library has loaded. When it does, it reads `_gaq` and replays the calls.

We decided to do this because our legacy code contains a lot of calls to a particular library which is loaded synchronously in `<head>`. This greatly increases the time to first contentful paint, as a lot of JS is evaluated and executed.

However, there are too many places in the code that would need to be changed (wrapped in a `'DOMContentLoaded'` listener), so we decided to try using  workaround.

We decided to try using `Proxy` to catch calls to our library's methods, and replay them once it's ready:

```js
// Original code:
var ourLib = new OurLib({ ... });

// Throughout the site, calls such as:
var res1 = ourLib.doThis();
var res2 = ourLib.getThat(3);
```

Here's a sort-of "simplified" version of what our new code is doing:

```js
// New code:
var ourLib = new Proxy({
    calls: [],
}, {
    get(target, prop) {
        if (prop in target) {
            return Reflect.get(...arguments);
        }

        const callref = { prop, args: [], placeholder };
        target.calls.push(callref);

        return function(...args) {
            const placeholder = MakeResultPlaceholder(...);

            callref.args = args;
            callref.placeholder = placeholder;

            return placeholder;
        };
    },
});

// Throughout the site, calls continue as before, except now they're 'stored' in `calls`
var res1 = ourLib.doThis();
var res2 = ourLib.getThat(3);

// Much later, the original lib is loaded, and 
var ourRealLib = new OurLib({ ... });
__playbackCalls(ourLib.calls, ourRealLib);

// Replace the proxy with the real thing
ourLib = ourRealLib;
```

After the run above, the `calls` property will be something like this:

```js
[
    {
        prop: 'doThis',
        args: [],
        reference: ResultPlaceholder
    },
    {
        prop: 'getThat',
        args: [3],
        reference: ResultPlaceholder
    }
]
```

The `__playbackCalls` function iterates through the `calls` array and `apply` each method from `ourRealLib` with the `args` stored in each object.

```js
calls.forEach(({ prop, args, reference }) => {
    reference._value = ourRealLib[prop].apply(ourRealLib, args);
});
```

The problem comes when the *result* of the proxy's calls needs to be used. Right now, as you can see, the calls return a `placeholder` object (which is in itself another proxy). These placeholders hold a `_value` property that becomes populated during "playback".

So here's the question:

- Let's say `ourLib.getThat()` is meant to return a `number`.
- During the first "run", because of the whole proxy thing, `res1` will point to a `placeholder` object: `Proxy { _value: undefined }`
- The real lib is loaded, "playback" finishes, `ourRealLib.getThat(3)` returns `23`, so `res1` will be `Proxy { _value: 23 }`
- Can I do **anything** so that we can use `res1` as a number? Something like:

```js
console.log(res1 * 2); // 46
```

Comment: no. You cannot. Also I doubt you really want that. Your example would work with `res1 = { getValue() { this._value; } };`  though.

Comment: @JonasWilms `getValue` or `valueOf` ?

Comment: valueOf, it's late ...

Comment: @JonasWilms the `valueOf` advice seems to do the job for me. It even works if `_value` is an actual object, not just primitives.

Why do you say you doubt I really want that? Are there any downsides to using it like that?

Comment: yes, I doubt your whole approach. I guess in the end rewriting the whole thing is much less pain

Comment: The approach of caching calls only works for Google Analytics because they are known not to return anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to proxy JavaScript creation primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60383942/1048572)?